# Fixing Android Studio radio button bug

Tags: android-studio, oop

I have 4 radio buttons in my app, which when when clicked excecutes the onClick method tipamount1:

```
            rad1.setChecked(false);
            rad2.setChecked(false);
            rad3.setChecked(false);
            rad4.setChecked(false);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(screen, "please enter a valid bill amount", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
        }
        String valueStr = totalinput.getText().toString();
        Double value = Double.parseDouble(valueStr);
        tipamount = 0.12*value;
        totalwithtip = tipamount+value;
        double roundOff = Math.round(tipamount * 100.0) / 100.0;
        double roundOff2 = Math.round(totalwithtip * 100.0) / 100.0;

        tipamounttext.setText(String.format("%d",roundOff));

        totalwithtiptext.setText(String.format("%",roundOff2));

        rad2.setEnabled(false);
        rad3.setEnabled(false);
        rad4.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

When I run the app and click on the first radiobutton, below is the error I am getting:

```
    Process: com.example.tipsplit, PID: 1967
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:144)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:144) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4403)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2885)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2839)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2524)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2459)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2870)
        at com.example.tipsplit.MainActivity.tipamount1(MainActivity.java:69)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:144) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

After looking at the line `at com.example.tipsplit.MainActivity.tipamount1(MainActivity.java:69) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)` , I found that it is the line `tipamounttext.setText(String.format("%d",roundOff));` that is causing this error. However I do not know why `tipamounttext` is responsible since I have it defined in my `onCreate` as shown below:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        totalinput = findViewById(R.id.totalamountinput);
        tipamounttext = findViewById(R.id.tipamountresult);
        totalwithtiptext = findViewById(R.id.totalwithtipresult);
        rad1 = findViewById(R.id.twelvepercent);
        rad2 = findViewById(R.id.fifteenpercent);
        rad3 = findViewById(R.id.eighteenpercent);
        rad4 = findViewById(R.id.twentypercent);
        screen = findViewById(R.id.totalbillinput);

    }
```

Comment: totalwithtiptext.setText(String.format("%",roundOff2)) is this typo while posting question or you missed %d in there ?

Comment: @A.Shenoy yes, I missed that. App still crashes after I click the first radio button

Comment: Is it a same error or new error because prev error I can see it said IllegallFormatConversionException.. so that seems to cause of %d thing.. what is the new error ?

Comment: @A.Shenoy Ah! that seemed to be the problem. I was incorrectly formatting the double